# How to do a text match?

Tags: c#, java

Example: 1) This is a ball.
         2) These are balloons.

Output: `ball matches`.

Above are the two text, how to get its similarity match?

Comment: Spaces " " don't count? Period doesn't count too? :)

Comment: Could you please mention you want to match substring i.e. "contains"? And which specific language?

Comment: please be more specific about what you mean by `similarity`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the similarity between the two strings, the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a commonly used algorithm. It tells you the number of characters you'd have to modify in the first string for it to be equal to the second string.

The Levenshtein algorithm accounts for insertion, deletion and substitutions of characters. The more advanced [Damerau–Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) algorithm also considers the transposition of characters.